# why does $\varphi'(N)=0$ in this proof?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

[Fulton's book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) on page 105 defines $N$:

[image]

Afterwards Fulton writes this solution for this lemma:

[image]

I didn't understand why $\varphi'(N)=0$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to check that $\varphi'$ vanishes on the generating set for $N$. For this, we compute directly
\begin{eqnarray}
\varphi'([x+y] - [x] - [y]) &=& D(x+y) - D(x) - D(y) \\
&=& D(x) + D(y) - D(x) - D(y) \\
&=& 0.
\end{eqnarray}
Similarly,
\begin{eqnarray}
\varphi'([\lambda x] - \lambda[x]) &=& D(\lambda x) - \lambda D(x) \\
&=& \lambda D(x) - \lambda D(x)
&=& 0.
\end{eqnarray}

Finally,

\begin{eqnarray}
\varphi'([xy] - x[y] - y[x]) &=& D(xy)- xD(y) - yD(x) \\
&=& (D(x)y + xD(y)) - xD(y) - yD(x) \\
&=& 0.
\end{eqnarray}
The takeaway from these computation is that the generators of $N$ are defined precisely to be killed by the map $\varphi'$. Compare their definitions with that of the derivation $D$.